# jupyter-notebook, ImportError: cannot import name 'Type'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am a Windows user, and I have installed Python 3.6 on my computer. In order to use Jupyter notebooks, I downloaded atom. I already installed ipython and pandas. After entering the command `jupyter notebook` on the command-line, my browser doesn't open jupyter notebook, instead I get the follow error message:

```
[C:\Users\ELIDAD>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\elidad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\elidad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\ELIDAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\elidad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\notebook\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .nbextensions import install_nbextension
  File "c:\users\elidad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 610, in <module>
    from .extensions import (
  File "c:\users\elidad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\notebook\extensions.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tornado.log import LogFormatter
  File "c:\users\elidad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\log.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tornado.escape import _unicode
  File "c:\users\elidad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\escape.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tornado.util import unicode_type
  File "c:\users\elidad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\util.py", line 21, in <module>
    from typing import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'Type']
```

So, what is the problem? I am new to python and jupyter notebook. Thank you very much.

Comment: looks like it is using python 3.5. Don't think that's the issue. but good to check the PATH

Comment: Since the error comes from importing `Type` (which works on my computer) I'd recommend you upgrade the `typing` library (since there are newer Python versions). Try running `pip install --upgrade typing` from the command line as an admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install anaconda ,

"*Anaconda is a free and open-source distribution of the Python and R programming languages for scientific computing, that aims to simplify package management and deployment* " (As on google)

and then try Jupyter notebook
link: https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

Answer (score 2):

It is because Python3.5 has its own version typing (https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), and it is incompatible with the installed version of jupyter/tornado
Upgrade to python3.6 could solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since the error seems to come from the tornado package,
i would try to reinstall tornado if this does not help I made the experience that the conda packages often work better in windows: so just reinstall jupyter notebook (best in a new env) using anaconda

Best of luck, installing jupyter notebook used to make me a lot of troubles as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3.5.1 and don't want to use Conda, downgrading the Tornado version allows it run. Current Tornado version is 6.0.3. I downgraded it 4.5.1 because I knew it worked. Other versions after this might also work. It's an easy fix without the need to update the Python version.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better to create a virtual environment. Then, re-install jupyter notebook under that environment.

Visit https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-jupyter-notebook-with-python-3-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.5.1 doesn't have typing.Type, so I upgraded my python version to 3.5.4 which did the trick, for more details, Please check below link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56159851/7741962

Answer (score 0):

This happens bcz python 3.5+ have own typing and that dont have Deque class
you can do one thing in protocol.py remove Deque from the import state and import Deque from collections this work for me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the error

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'Type']
```

Just upgrade or use `Python 3.5.4` that will solve the issue.