# ImportError while importing sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, sympy

I installed sympy using pip and tried importing but it gives me an ImportError.

```
>>> import sympy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    import sympy
  File "C:\Users\Alok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sympy\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from .core import (sympify, SympifyError, cacheit, Basic, Atom,
  File "C:\Users\Alok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .sympify import sympify, SympifyError
  File "C:\Users\Alok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\sympify.py", line 3, in <module>
    from typing import Dict, Type, Callable, Any
ImportError: cannot import name 'Type'
```

Comment: show your pip list output? try creating virtualenv and install sympy in it..

Comment: Is `sympy` installed in the same environment as you run it from?

Comment: Does this issue seems related to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55210213/jupyter-notebook-importerror-cannot-import-name-type

Comment: I checked the pip list output
sympy v1.6 and mpmath v1.1.0 both are installed (and mpmath gets imported without issues)

Comment: @S.Iakovlev It works fine on my anaconda distribution but not with this universal environment (or whatever you call it) which i have

Comment: @VinitNeogi Type is not supported in python 3.5.1(the version i have). Time to upgrade!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19426